# error: module not found: twilio (with javafx module)

Tags: gradle, javafx, twilio, module-info

I have a problem with the twilio module not being found in the project when using the javafx structure.

### Error displayed:

```
13:50:40: Executing ':Main.main()'...


> Task :compileJava FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
1 actionable task: 1 executed
C:\Users\kksia\IDEA\Tinder\src\main\java\module-info.java:6: error: module not found: twilio
    requires twilio;
             ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --info option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 531ms
13:50:40: Execution finished ':Main.main()'.
```

### My current state of the module-info.java file:

```
module com.tinder {

    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires twilio;

    opens com.tinder to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.tinder;
    opens com.tinder.app to javafx.fxml ;
    exports com.tinder.app;
    exports com.tinder.app.controller;
    opens com.tinder.app.controller to javafx.fxml;
}
```

### And the build.gradle file which indicates that the twilio library has been downloaded:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}
group = "com.tinder"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
javafx {
    version = "21.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28")
    implementation("com.twilio.sdk:twilio:10.1.0" )
    implementation("com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.+" )
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.+" )

}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

I searched the entire internet, but none of the articles helped, so I thought I had to ask you about it. The only thing I found out on my own is that when using twilio on a pure gradle application, everything works, however, after adding the javafx structure to the application, the twilio module is not found.

#### PhoneCheckController.java (The IDE doesn't show any errors.)

[image: PhoneCheckController.java (The IDE doesn't show any errors.)]

Comment: It's not Javafx, that causes this. It's the way Gradle treats the dependencies without an explicit module name categorising this dependency on the classpath; hence, the automatic module cannot be inferred. You have a few alternatives - switch to Maven instead of Gradle to ease this declaration - not move to a modular application - wrap this dependency within a modular app as a fat jar and use that. Meanwhile, for a better/long-term solution, I have proposed the declaration of an [explicit module name](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/pull/784) verified on a similar local setup as shared.

Comment: I tried testing the module: `$ jar --file=twilio-10.1.0.jar --describe-module
No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module. twilio@10.1.0 automatic`. The class is built as an automatic module.  I don't use gradle, but I think it puts automatic modules on the classpath rather than the module path by default (maven does the opposite).  You probably need to add some kind of configuration switch to gradle if you want to be able to make it use automatic modules.  Consult the gradle documentation.

Comment: IMO a better/long-term solution, instead of adding an automatic module name to the jar, would be for the twilio maintainers to define a `module-info.java` and make the jar a proper module that can be used for dependency analysis and with tools such as `jlink`.

Comment: Don't screenshot text. Put code in the question as text, formatted as code.

Comment: @jewelsea To take the side of maintainers, while creating a modular application in itself could be a mammoth ask. To start with a declaration for clients consuming the library would be a much better/quicker option. Though I agree the ideal situation to be is making use of the modular application, that transition though would happen gradually.

Comment: @Naman sorry for stating something quite off-topic and I commend your efforts.  But this is a `com.twilio` module, meaning the maintainers are Twilio themselves.  Twilio is a 11.3 billion dollar technology company with over a thousand engineers.  Java has been modularized for over seven years.  That such a company would not produce a well-specified module or even document how to use their software in a modular application is beyond disappointing.  And, yes, Twilio are not the only technology company failing in this regard.